# Approach to import/export SQL Server stored procedures

Tags: c#, sql-server, batch-file

I know most people will give responses like, right click database name, select task, generate scripts, etc. Most people give detail response on the internet include stackoverflow

I already know that long time ago.

My question is any suggestions to write scripts to export/import stored procedures. If I only have to do 5 or 10, it is no big issue. I just have to pick right ones. If there are lots like 50 or more, it is pain and bound to be errors. Sometimes, to make life easier, we want to export/import with suffix such as `*test.sql`.

Any suggestion using SQL scripts, C# or dos commands to do so?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged also C#. With .NET you can do it using [Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx). There is a [StoredProcedure class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.storedprocedure.aspx). This approach gives you really lots of control over the task you want to achieve. Example usage you can find [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.database.storedprocedures.aspx), also using PowerShell.

Here's a snippet I've put together that might help you(uses `Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo`, `Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo`, `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc` DLLs):

```
var serverConnection = new ServerConnection(new SqlConnection(ConnectionString));
var server = new Server(serverConnection);
foreach (StoredProcedure sp in server.Databases["YourDB"].StoredProcedures)
{
    if (sp.Name.Contains("yourSubstring"))
    {
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(sp.TextHeader + Environment.NewLine + sp.TextBody);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why have you tagged this question with C# when you ask for answers in SQL or DOS script?

This CMD script drops all stored procedures whose names begin with "usp":

```
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`sqlcmd -S %SERVER% -d %DATABASE% -Q "select name from sys.objects where type = 'P'" `) DO (echo %%F | findstr "^usp" >nul 2>&1 && sqlcmd -S %SERVER% -d %DATABASE% -Q "drop procedure %%F" )
```

It's all on one line and %SERVER% and %DATABASE% identify the server and database.

This script loads all stored procedures from the current directory whose names match "usp*.sql". You will need the setting QUOTED_IDENTIFIER to be ON if you invoke XML data type methods.

```
for %%f in (usp*.sql) do sqlcmd  -S %SERVER% -d %DATABASE% -I -i %%f
```

Comment: Thanks. Which parameter is for export? I just did sqlcmd help, and I could not find export or script routine. One reason to write a batch is to export a bunch of files. You did put down drop procedure. It is still helpful although I would not want to write a batch program to drop a bunch of SP. That is too much risk.  Oh, the reason I tag C#, I am just curious if there is an API to do so. If batch can do it, it serves the purpose

Comment: "How to export stored procedures to text files" (http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic205892-5-1.aspx) shows several techniques. Probably the one you want is to open the database in SSMS, right-click on the database name and select Tasks -> Generate Scripts; then follow the wizard.

Comment: Tasks -> Generate Scripts is the step I already know. One time, I had to export 50+ sp. It was pain, and ended up I export the one I was not supposed to export. I also miss couple one. When I have to export 50+ sp in 500+ sp, the chance of clicking the wrong SP is highly likely. I am going to do  same thing again soon. This time I have to prepare the scripts for someone else. It would be nice if there is an easier. I will try BCP_utility, http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/bcp-and-sp_helptext-to-script-store-procedures-into-seperate-files.aspx, I hope that will help